# Policy to block s3 upload based on ec2 instance tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

Is there any way to apply restriction in s3 buckets using ec2 instance tag.

We have couple of ec2 instances. But we want to allow upload to s3 from ec2 instances which have specific tag.

Comment: Show some code what you have tried.

Comment: as far as I know you cannot have the `ec2:ResourceTag` condition for an s3 bucket ... you could use though a policy with `aws:SourceIp` condition

Comment: Can you provide details of *why* you wish to accomplish this? There might be another way to achieve your goal.

Comment: it's like I have existing ec2 instances with IAM role, say with PutObject access only. Now some of this instances me and my friend will use, where he should not have access to my bucket and I should not have of his. As because I am not creating ec2 from scratch I have to use the instance with the same IAM role. But on top of that I want to put a restriction like I said already. And consider we don't have user account in AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to write a policy that restricts upload to Amazon S3 to only come from Amazon EC2 instances that have a specific tag.

The reason is that the request to Amazon S3 comes from a User or Role identified by the Access Key. Amazon S3 will check permissions against that User or Role. It cannot check details of the Amazon EC2 instance from which it was 'sent'.

One option is to assign those Amazon EC2 instances a specific role that includes permissions for Amazon S3, while other instances have a different role.

Comment: Actually we already have some ec2 instance with putObject policy in the attached IAM role. Later we created s3 buckets. Now we have to restrict s3 upload as per tagging or any other way if possible. So that some group of instaces have access to specific s3 bucket and some other have in other bucket and so.